# How to limit number of Vim-LSP suggestions from Vim-LSP itself

Tags: lsp, popup-menu

Even though Vim has its `pum` stuff, more specifically `pumheight` for this problem, I would expect [Vim-LSP (prabirshrestha/vim-lsp)](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/vim-lsp) to have something similar for itself as well, after all a language server can't spew out an infinite number of suggestions.

Does anyone know if there really is such a thing?

My intention on going through this route, instead of being satisfied with `pumheight`, is to find out a more LSP-native way of dealing with these things, which will probably prove to be a more viable alternative if I have a more complicated LSP setup problem in the future.

Comment: isn't that more an issue for the plugins issue tracker?

Comment: Maybe. But what sealed the deal for me to put it here was the fact that, if anyone else comes up with another LSP similar plugin in the future, this type of rationel would still apply. Besides, having an alternative to `pumheight` documented here is also useful.

Comment: Vim itself doesn't know anything about LSP so this question is seriously off-topic.